# Emulating a HID and RNDIS network device simultaneously using gadgets via USB OTG

Tags: linux, networking, drivers, usb, configuration

I am trying to emulate a HID and a network device on a Raspberry Pi which has USB OTG. The requirements are the following:

- Network needs to work under Windows
- HID and network should work at the same time

I looked through lots of posts and am not able to find a documentation for the Linux gadgets that explains how everything works.

What I have found and what works really well with Linux is [this solution](https://github.com/crmulliner/hidemulation/blob/master/hidnet.sh) from the USB Armory Project. This solution uses ECM mode for the network. Windows somehow recognizes the device but does not get the right drivers. The only drivers I was able to find need to be bought and are really expensive. According to [this post](https://github.com/jeffegg/beaglebone/blob/master/Documentation/usb/gadget_multi.txt#windows-host-drivers) it should work if only one config is used.

So as I see it there are 2 possible solutions to this:

- Getting Windows to install and use the right drivers for ECM mode
- Getting RNDIS mode to work with HID enabled at the same time

I already tried to get both solutions to work. A single network with RNDIS works (see code below) and a single HID also works.

```
#!/bin/bash -e
modprobe libcomposite
cd /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/
mkdir g && cd g

echo 0x1d6b > idVendor  # Linux Foundation
echo 0x0104 > idProduct # Multifunction Composite Gadget
echo 0x0100 > bcdDevice # v1.0.0
echo 0x0200 > bcdUSB    # USB 2.0

echo 0xEF > bDeviceClass
echo 0x02 > bDeviceSubClass
echo 0x01 > bDeviceProtocol

mkdir -p strings/0x409
echo "affeaffe"    > strings/0x409/serialnumber
echo "myself"         > strings/0x409/manufacturer
echo "myproduct"        > strings/0x409/product

mkdir -p functions/rndis.usb0  # network
mkdir -p configs/c.1

echo 250 > configs/c.1/MaxPower
ln -s functions/rndis.usb0 configs/c.1/

echo 1       > os_desc/use
echo 0xcd    > os_desc/b_vendor_code
echo MSFT100 > os_desc/qw_sign

echo RNDIS   > functions/rndis.usb0/os_desc/interface.rndis/compatible_id
echo 5162001 > functions/rndis.usb0/os_desc/interface.rndis/sub_compatible_id

ln -s configs/c.1 os_desc
udevadm settle -t 5 || :

ls /sys/class/udc/ > UDC

ip link set usb0 up
```